# Inconsistent with StringBuilder append in a loop

Tags: loops, append, iteration, stringbuilder

I have a problem with using StringBuilder below in the loop as the output is inconsistent.  Please help!!!

```
String oldStr = "job1.job2.job3";
String[] newStr = oldStr.split(Pattern.quote("."));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (String temp : newStr) {    
    String key = "This is "+keyStr+" ,";
    result.append(key);
    System.out.println(key.toString());
}
```

I expect result to be

```
This is job1.  
This is job1.  This is job2.
This is job1.  This is job2.  This is job3.
```

I did see the expected result at one point but then I'm seeing these now:

```
This is job1.  
This is job2.  
This is job3.
```

If I continue to run the code, I'm seeing multiple elements:

```
This is job1.  
This is job2.  
This is job3.
This is job1.  
This is job2.  
This is job3.
```

Is there issue with my code or StringBuilder is not behaving correctly as it should?  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
System.out.println(key.toString());
```

to

```
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Not sure how I could miss that.  This works for me now.